# Appending an element to a cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with an HTML table that has a button `(#addRows)` that when clicked will clone the first table row and append it to the bottom of the table.

This table resides in a section of HTML with some other input fields that can also be cloned and appended onto the bottom of my form. When I am cloning the section I am changing all child element ID's to include a number that can be iterated dependent on how many times the user clones the section.

Example

```
<div id="someID"> ... </div>
<div id="someID2"> ... </div>
<div id="someID3"> ... </div>
```

I am doing this with JQuery like this

```
$(function() {    
  var $section = $("#facility_section_info").clone();
  var $cloneID = 1; 
    $( ".addSection" ).click(function() { 
        var $sectionClone = $section.clone(true).find("*[id]").andSelf().each(function() { $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + $cloneID); });
        $('#facility_section_info').append($sectionClone);
        $cloneID++; 
    });
});
```

When I clone the section that holds the table I am also cloning the `#addRows` button which when clicked should append a table row to the table it is being clicked on. However if I clone my section and I click on my second `#addRows button it will clone my table row but it is appending to my first table and not the second.

Here is my `addRows` button and event handler

```
<input type="button" value="+" id="addRows" class="addRows"/>

$(function() {
    var $componentTB = $("#component_tb"),
        $firstTRCopy = $("#row0").clone();
        $idVal = 1;
        $(document).on('click', '.addRows', function(){
            var copy = $firstTRCopy.clone(true);
            var newId = 'row' +$idVal;
            copy.attr('id', newId);
            $idVal += 1;
            copy.children('td').last().append("<a href=\"javascript:remove('" + newId + "')\">Remove</a>");
            $componentTB.append(copy);
        });
});
```

My question is, when I clone my section of HTML that holds my table and `#addButton` how can I ensure that when the user clicks on the original button it will clone and append to that table **or** if I click the cloned button it will clone and append to the cloned table only?

If anything is unclear please let me know so I can try to better explain what I am trying to do, thanks.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72uLwuwc/) demonstrating the problem I am having.

Comment: Yes, it would be great if you could replicate the problem in a JSFiddle

Comment: @ArinCool added the jsfiddle

Comment: @BigRabbit if you already have question chain why you added new one ?

Comment: @nirmal read the question and you'll notice there is only a single table I am dealing with, I just added a second table and was having a separate issue. Also notice how I deleted the new question ? ;) Thanks for stopping by though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I truly love you BigRabbit, here is where I got to. You will see at least one useful fix here:

```
    var $sectionClone = $section.clone(true);
    $sectionClone.find("*[id]").andSelf().each(function () {
        $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + $cloneID);
    });
```

and a fix for an issue you did not report yet

```
$copy.children('td').last().append(' <a href="#" class="remove" data-removeid="'+newId + '">Remove</a>');
```

using

```
$("#facility_section_info").on('click', '.remove', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#"+$(this).data("removeid")).remove();
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/6pqw5yh8/)

```
$(function () {
    var $componentTB = $("#component_tb"),
        $firstTRCopy = $("#row0").clone(),
        $section = $("#facility_section_info>fieldset").clone(),
        $cloneID = 0,
        $idVal = 0;

    $("#facility_section_info").on('click', '.remove', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#"+$(this).data("removeid")).remove();
    });

    $("#facility_section_info").on('click', '.addRows', function () {
        $idVal++;
        var $copy = $firstTRCopy.clone(true);
        var newId = 'row' + $idVal;
        $copy.attr('id', newId);
        $copy.children('td').last().append(' <a href="#" class="remove" data-removeid="'+newId + '">Remove</a>');
        $(this).closest("fieldset").find("tbody").append($copy);
    });

    $("#facility_section_info").on("click", ".addSection", function () {
        $cloneID++;
        var $sectionClone = $section.clone(true);
        $sectionClone.find("*[id]").andSelf().each(function () {
            $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + $cloneID);
        });
        $('#facility_section_info').append($sectionClone);

    });
});
```

Comment: Love you too. I appreciate the extra's however I already had a solution for my remove link, but I like your solution a lot better. I did notice however when I click on the add section in your fiddle that it clones the table twice, how can I fix that?, I do see though that when I click the `+` button I do add the rows to the proper table, as well as the remove :) Thanks, I am a very GRATEFUL brat :)

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured, there is a bunch of new stuff here so it's a little difficult for me to iron this out, but I will continue to try, if you happen to figure something out please let me know, thanks again.

Comment: AH, I get TWO fieldsets. - Changed to `$section = $("#facility_section_info>fieldset").clone()`